# WPF, 3d camera won't rotate correctly

Tags: .net, wpf, perspectivecamera

EDIT

Oh, and one more thing, longtitute works great, but when lattitute reached about 1.57 it flips over...

[image]

**EDIT WORKS!**

oh, only the rotation speed starts to build up when it makes more the one turn. guess have to reset the tempMouse after each rotation.

```
    private void mouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs  e)
    {
        if (e.Delta < 0) { distance = distance - 0.5; } else { distance = distance + 0.5; }

        Point3D position = new Point3D
            (
                Math.Cos(longitude) * Math.Cos(latitude) * distance,
                Math.Sin(latitude) * distance,
                Math.Sin(longitude) * Math.Cos(latitude) * distance
            );

       _perspectiveCamera.Position = position;
    }


    private void mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if ( e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed )
        {
            if (isLeftDown == false)
            {
                isLeftDown = true;
                tempMouseX = this.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this)).X;
                tempMouseY = this.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this)).Y;
            }
            else
            {
                double currentDelataX = tempMouseX - this.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this)).X;
                double currentDelataY = tempMouseY - this.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this)).Y;

                longitude = longitude - currentDelataX / 5000;
                latitude = latitude - currentDelataY / 5000;



                Point3D objectPosition = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);

                Point3D position = new Point3D
                    (
                        Math.Cos(longitude) * Math.Cos(latitude) * distance,
                        Math.Sin(latitude) * distance,
                        Math.Sin(longitude) * Math.Cos(latitude) * distance
                    );

                _perspectiveCamera.Position = position;

                Vector3D lookDirection = objectPosition - position;
                _perspectiveCamera.LookDirection = lookDirection;


            }

        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
        {
            isLeftDown = false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What's the camera `UpDirection`?

Comment: How do you expect the above code to rotate anything? There is just a translation of the camera position. Bzw, you should update `tempMouseY` and `tempMouseX`. Otherwise, the `deltas` will get quite big.

Comment: UpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);   but that is it anyway?  I assume the camera would rotate by moving its position and still keeping it pointed at the center of the world.

Comment: Re: Edit - Looks like you forgot to reassign the camera position. And maybe there's a sign wrong somewhere.

Comment: Try switching `objectPosition` and `position` in your `lookDirection`. Maybe I got it backwards.

Comment: Oh, I think the problem is that you have a negative `distance`. Change it to just `5`.

Comment: changed to 5, and tried swapping Vector3D lookDirection = position - objectPosition;, still the same (

Comment: I was wrong about subtraction. Change it back to how it was. And remember to assign your position. It's commented out.

Comment: see edit above, the moving part works, by the rotating turns the camera into nowhere.

Comment: oh, on the other hand by _perspectiveCamera.Position = new Point3D(_posX, _posY, _posZ); I'm just moving it on a plane, not a sphere...

Comment: You need to set your camera's position to `position`. Your `_pos` variables should be eliminated from your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to move the camera on a sphere, rather than a plane as you are doing now.

Rather than storing the position of the camera in Euclidean coordinates, store it in spherical coordinates.

```
double distance;
double latitude;
double longitude;
```

In the mouse wheel handler, simply increase/decrease `distance`.

In the mouse move handler, adjust `latitude` proportional to the Y delta (you might want to limit it to +/-pi/2, so that you don't overshoot the poles), and `longitude` proportional to the X delta.

To calculate your position, use something like this:

```
Point3D position = new Point3D
(
    Math.Cos(longitude) * Math.Cos(latitude) * distance,
    Math.Sin(latitude) * distance,
    Math.Sin(longitude) * Math.Cos(latitude) * distance
);
// This line is just a simplified version of your LookDirection calculation
Vector3D lookDirection = objectPosition - position;
```

Comment: rarely I see answers that beautiful, very elegant :) I would +2 if I could.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kendall, looks correct, but as I implemented it ( see edit above ), the camera just swaps to black... did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "swaps to black"?

Comment: The object that's in the center is not seen, i.e. camera is pointing somewhere else.

Comment: See my comment on the question. I think you have a bad `distance`.

Comment: fixed the distance, didn't help (

Answer (score 0):

Following code is for rotation of camera as trackball.

```
                Point currentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
                var diff = currentMousePosition - previousMousePosition;

                // Get the camera's position
                var camP = new Vector3D(camera.Position.X, camera.Position.Y, camera.Position.Z);
                double radius = camP.Length; // Replace with the actual radius of the sphere


                var m = new Vector3D(diff.X,diff.Y,0);
                m.Normalize();
                // Calculate the spherical angles based on the camera position
                // theta+=Math.Acos(camP.Y / radius); // Azimuth angle θ
                 //phi+=Math.Atan2(-camP.Z, camP.X); // Inclination or polar angle φ

                // Sensitivity factor for controlling the rotation speed
                double sensitivity = 0.01;

                // Accumulate the mouse movements
                theta -= m.Y ;
                phi -= m.X ;

                // Clamp the theta angle within a range to prevent issues near poles
                theta = Clamp(theta, 0.0001, Math.PI - 0.0001);

                // Calculate Cartesian coordinates from spherical coordinates
                double x = radius * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Cos(phi);
                double z = -radius * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Sin(phi);
                double y = radius * Math.Cos(theta);

                var p = new Vector3D(x, y, z);

                // Set the camera's position and look direction
                camera.Position = new Point3D(p.X, p.Y, p.Z);
                camera.LookDirection = -p;

                // Calculate the new UpDirection (maintaining orthogonality)
                Vector3D newUpDirection = Vector3D.CrossProduct(-p, camera.UpDirection);
                newUpDirection.Normalize();
                camera.UpDirection = newUpDirection;

                // Update the previous mouse position for the next iteration
                previousMousePosition = currentMousePosition;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).